# Prove that $((u(t,x)-v(t,x))^+)^{1/k} \le Ce^{t\alpha}\|u - v\|_\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How can I prove that 
$$((u(t,x)-v(t,x))^+)^{1/k} \le Ce^{t\alpha}\|u - v\|_\infty,$$
where $C$ is a constant, $u,v$ are continuous on $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}$, $T \in (0,\infty)$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\alpha >0$ and $(\cdot)^+$ is the positive part function?

Comment: Is $C$ the same for all $u,v$?

Comment: @Vim Yes, it is.

Comment: This can't quite be right.  Consider $u(x)=a$, $v(x)=0$.  Then the left hand side is $a^{1/k}$ and the right hand side is $a$.  The ratio $a^{1/k-1}$ isn't bounded as $a\to 0$.  Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: @felipeh You're right. I edited the question.

Comment: @Riku if $\alpha$ is just a constant it can just be absorbed into $C$. Did you actually mean $e^{\alpha x}$?

Comment: @Vim I edited the question.

Comment: felipeh example continues to apply. You have $1\le Ce^{\alpha t}a^{1-1/k}\to 0$ as $a\to 0^+$

Comment: @Gio67 Thanks for your comment. Then what similar estimates can we have? Also, what would change if we had $k = 1$?

Comment: If $k\ge 2$ then the only inequality you have is $x^{1/k}\le 1+x$ for all $x\ge 0$. So you should replace $\Vert u-v\Vert_\infty$ with $1+\Vert u-v\Vert_\infty$. For $k=1$ your inequality works fine with $C=1$ and any $\alpha>0$

Comment: @Gio67 Could you expand on that in an answer?